# Is there a way to detect when the Facebook permissions dialog is shown?

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm using the FB Javascript SDK, and handling login via a custom button that calls `FB.login`. Ideally, I'd like to be able to record some tracking data whenever a user is shown the app approval/permissions dialog so that I can see how many users bomb out at this stage. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a reliable way of achieving this.

If the user is already logged in to FB, I can infer whether it will be shown by checking the login status before calling `FB.login`. If the user is `not_authorized`, then I know the permissions dialog will be shown. But if the user is not logged in, my information is more limited. I can assume that the user *was* shown the dialog if they finish the process as `not_authorized`, but if they end up being `connected` then I have no way of distinguishing between a user who was already connected and one who just gave approval.

I'd hoped that the `auth.prompt` event might help, but it doesn't seem to be fired for the sequence starting from `FB.login`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally, I'd like to be able to record some tracking data whenever a user is shown the app approval/permissions dialog so that I can see how many users bomb out at this stage.

Look at your app insights, there you’ll see Auth Dialog Conversions.

No need for own tracking for that.

Comment: Doh! Didn't even think of looking for that. Thanks, that's perfect